# Async mapLimit change limit

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Is there a way to change the limit parameter in async.mapLimit once the function has been called?

I'm creating a http loader and want to reduce the limit if http errors start to occur.

https://github.com/caolan/async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `mapLimit` method to `queue`

https://github.com/caolan/async#queueworker-concurrency

it's allow change `concurrency` parameter on the fly